# iPhone, can I test my own ad-hoc distirbution on the iTouch I normally use with my max and a usb cable?

Tags: iphone

I'm probably getting mixed up, but I use my itouch with xcode and have xcode launch my app on my itouch. I normally have it in debug.

Can I test the ad-hoc distribution and mobile provision on my itouch ?

I have my friends udid and my itouchs udid in the provision.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

yes you can go to the build menu and choice build and archive.
Now via the organizer you can send the ipa to an email address or save it locally.

The ipa can be installed via iTunes by simple dragging it to the apps section.
Or you can use organizer to install the ipa on the connected device.

Comment: Validate will check if your app is valid for the app store. Your friend does not have to remove any thing if he is running iOS 4.0 or higher. The provisioning profiles are in the IPA. Also check out [TestFlightApp](http://www.testflightapp.com/) for easy distribution without the use on iTunes, it installs direct on the device.

Answer (score 0):

You can use build and run. As the entitlements are not set to allow debugging the app will crash shortly after launching, but the binary will be on your phone. Launch again to use as normal